# renderHead is not called

Tags: java, wicket

I have a class `CloakDecorator` which implements `IAjaxCallDecorator` and `IHeaderContributor`:

```
public class CloakDecorator implements IAjaxCallDecorator, IHeaderContributor {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final ResourceReference INDICATOR = new ResourceReference(CloakDecorator.class, "indicator.gif");
    private static final ResourceReference JS = new JavascriptResourceReference(CloakDecorator.class, "CloakDecorator.js");
    private static final ResourceReference CSS = new ResourceReference(CloakDecorator.class, "CloakDecorator.css");

    public CloakDecorator() {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response) {
        System.out.println("renderHead");
        response.renderCSSReference(CSS);
        response.renderJavascriptReference(JS);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence decorateScript(CharSequence script) {
        return script;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence decorateOnSuccessScript(CharSequence script) {
        return script;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence decorateOnFailureScript(CharSequence script) {
        return script;
    }
}
```

Now from an AjaxLink I am instantiating `CloakDecorator`:

```
AjaxLink link=new AjaxLink("") {

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    }

    @Override
    protected IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator() {
        return new CloakDecorator();
    }
};
```

The problem is that the constructor of `CloakDecorator` is called but the `renderHead` method is not called. What I am doing wrong? I have placed some `System.out.println` in constructor and in `renderHead` method, the `System.out.println` of constructor is working but the second one not.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, simply implementing `IHeaderContributor` does not guarantee that you will actually contribute to the header of the page/component.  This only works for instances of `Component` and `IBehavior` elements that are added to the page and the page itself.  Specifically from the javadoc of `IHeaderContributor`:

```
An interface to be implemented by components or behaviors that wish to 
contribute to the header section of the page.
```

The specific code that calls this is in `Component#renderHead(HtmlHeaderContainer)`.  It checks to see if itself and any of its behaviors implement `IHeaderContributor` and then adds those contributions.

To solve your problem, you can either:

1. Have your `AjaxLink` implement `IHeaderContributor`
2. Add an `IBehavior` to your `AjaxLink` that implements `IHeaderContributor`

Depending on how often you will use this, Option #1 might be the best.  Create a "CloakedAjaxLink" that does all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Since Wicket 1.5 IAjaxCallDecorators can also contribute to the header if they implement IComponentAwareHeaderContributor.

Comment: I am using wicket 1.3.6, is it possible to have it there?

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading to at least Wicket 1.4 - there is some migration overhead, but it's a grand improvement.  In either case, I don't think you will get this capability as it is in Wicket 1.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a IHeaderContributor to a component to make it actually "contribute" to the document. The way you're using it you're using only half of the implementation you want. I suggest you to split your implementation or to write a CloakLink including this code which will be able to contribute to the page where its added.